# change the label.text in C#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie with C#. I am trying to show how much times the button is clicked, here is my code below:

```
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int i = 0;     
      while (true)    
       {              
         label1.Text = i.ToString();
         i += 1;   
       }
}
```

code runs fine, but label.text is not changing when I clicked the button. I also cannot identify any problem by using break points.
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: its because your loop is infinite looped meaning until the while condition gets falls the label can't be shown and since you while loop is always true the lifecycle of click function will not complete and will not show result i say just put a correct logical while loop and it willl work

Comment: Apart from all the correct answers you already have, it's worth noticing that the infinite loop you have shows a misunderstanding about events. You don't have to loop to check if the button is clicked, when it's clicked the event is raised and your event handler `ClickMebutton_Click` is called. You should read more on events

Comment: Thanks all! now it is working perfectly. Sorry to bother you guys with an such easy question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 0; // 1

private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++; // 3
    label1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comments:

1. Store counter outside of event handler body. Otherwise, it will reset to `0` each time you click on the button. You can also parse label text instead of storing counter in the class field.
2. Remove infinite while loop
3. Increment counter *before* you assign text. Otherwise, after first click you will have `0`

Solution with parsing label text:

Note that initially you should set label text to `"0"`. Do it in the designer. Thus after application start label will show correct information - button was clicked zero times.

```
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = Int32.Parse(label1.Text);
    i++;
    label1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should define i publicly

```
 private int i = 0;     
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     i++;          
     label1.Text = i.ToString();


 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is not changing since your are having an infinite loop here:

```
 while (true)
```

If you put your break point on that **spot**, you are just looping and looping that's why you cannot see the changes. Make this:

```
int i = 0;
```

A global variable, and remove your infinite loop which you don't really need on your logic:

```
private int i = 0;     
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){   

  i++;
  label1.Text = i.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove *infinite loop* (`while (true)`), but add `1` to the `label1.Text`:

```
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int value;

  if (int.TryParse(label1.Text, out value))
    label1.Text = (value + 1).ToString();
  else
    label1.Text = "1";
}
```

In case of *C# 7.0+* you can put it terser, but less readable:

```
private void ClickMebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  label1.Text = (int.TryParse(label1.Text, out var value) ? value + 1 : 1).ToString();
}
```